# row number always return 1 for each row in sql server

Tags: row-number

```
(SELECT 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by t.NotificationID)) as  RowNumber,
            [NotificationID],[ProjectID],[TeamMemberID],[OperationType],
            [Hours],[Occurance],[Period],[NotificationText],
            [NotificationRecipientIDs],[NotificationRecipientClienitsIDs]

       FROM tblIA_Notifications t
       WHERE IsDeleted = 0 AND IsActive = 1
    )
```

The above query always returns rownumber 1 for each row. When I use the select statement outside, its problem. Otherwise if I remove the outer select statement its fine.

I don't understand the behavior.

Comment: The case is when i use select statement outside then its problem, otherwise if i remove outer select statement its fine

Comment: Why do you have outer select statement? Cant you directly use inner query for your business logic?

Comment: i use to do it for select and insert it in other table, thats why i did so, but that is not constraint , i have removed outer select , and my query is ok, but just i want to understand why its behaving so, with row number

Answer (score 4):

Uou are getting row_number 1 for each row because you are selecting the Row_Number for each row
try this--->

```
SELECT        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by t.NotificationID) as RowNumber,
              [NotificationID],
              [ProjectID],
              [TeamMemberID],
              [OperationType],
              [Hours],
              [Occurance],
              [Period],
              [NotificationText],
              [NotificationRecipientIDs],
              [NotificationRecipientClienitsIDs]
    FROM      tblIA_Notifications    t 
    WHERE     IsDeleted    =    0 
    AND       IsActive = 1
```

Comment: The case is when i use select statement outside then its problem, otherwise if i remove outer select statement its fine

Comment: can u paste your full sql query here ?

Comment: i have post in my question , that is full query , if you remove select ( from first line, it will work, otherwise it wont, i just wanna know its behavior why its doing so

Comment: i dont think there is any problem in above query, may b the problem in somewhere else.. !

Comment: You try any query in the given pattern,

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by T.COLUMN_NAME) as RowNumber FROM [dbo].[TABLE_NAME] T
```